# Spring Security 6 configuration with multiple security configs

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

I'm trying to setup my Spring Boot 3.0 / Spring Security 6 app with multiple security configs.

- **only** `/oauth/token` should use/allow/enforce basic auth
- all other endpoints will use/allow/enforce bearer auth

The issue I'm running into is that if I send a `GET` request to `/test` with the header `Authorization: Basic xxx` the basic auth filter is still picking it up.

This is what I have so far. The bearer filter isn't implemented yet, but for the sake of this question, let's assume all other endpoints should be wide open instead. How can I get them to bypass the basic auth filter if a user passes in basic auth header?

```java
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable)
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/oauth/token").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
        .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

    return http.build();
  }
```

Comment: You can't do it with Spring Security's basic auth filter, you have to implement a custom filter. Another way is to implement to filter chains. One for basic auth an the other for OAuth2 token.

Comment: Check out this [section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity_instances) of the documentation to see how to configure multiple `SecurityFilterChain`s.

Answer (score 1):

Like this one:

```java
    private static final String[] RESOURCE_ARGS = new String[]{
        "/test/**"
    };

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(RESOURCE_ARGS).permitAll();

        http
            .csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/oauth/token").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
        .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        ....
    }
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't change anything, OP already uses `.anyRequest().permitAll()`, that includes `/test/**`.

Answer (score 1):

I've spent several hours to migrate to spring security 6. I had 4 configurations and now can share my experience.

Firstly, you need to add second `@Bean` of `SecurityFilterChain`, be ready to specify their order using `@Order(1)` and `@Order(2)` for example.

Make sure you filled `requestMatchers`, this method allows to separate security filtering logic, fill it for example with `/oauth/token` for basic auth and `/test` for bearer. I think it's better to use `/test/**`, it be allowed to filter all paths under `/test`.

Be careful of using `formLogin`, it can redirect to login page instead of throwing error.

You might want to add some different `AuthenticationProvider` for those chains, it's ok to create such beans with different names. Note that only one `AuthenticationManager` should be present:

```
    @Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(List<AuthenticationProvider> authenticationProviders) {
    return new ProviderManager(authenticationProviders);
}
```